# Firebase unable to process request due to missing initial state

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, mobile

I am trying to use phone auth from `firebase` and I get this error now.

Unable to process request due to missing initial state. This may happen if browser session storage is inaccessible or accidentally cleared.

This was working a week ago and no longer works.

Comment: It's possible that your issue is linked to this ongoing problem. I would start here and work from there. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/4256

Comment: Sometimes error can be due to a wrong Authorization callback URL in GitHub

Answer (score 16):

I have solved this by registering my app with SafetyNet with SHA2. To do this follow these steps:

1. Get your SHA2. If you don't know how to get this, follow this tutorial:
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kLaNnuoqnmA
   Note. This youtube link is for SHA1 but you will notice that SHA2 will be shown here if you pay attention.
2. Go to your Firebase Console then, go to Project Settings > App Check. You will notice your app is "Unregistered." click this to register your app.
3. Enter the SHA2 you copied and Accept some terms below then click Save. you will notice the "Registered" with green check icon.

Btw, this error happens on one of my devices but not on another. I also searched through this error and no one has solved this including this page. This happens in my phone authentication using firebase when getting an OTP as I send my phone number. The app tries to redirect you to a browser for Recaptcha for verification if you don't have SafetyNet. Thus, having no SafetyNet will cause your app to always be redirected for Recaptcha which sometimes causes an error. Thus, to solve this, register your app with Safety Net. to understand this, read this documentation.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth?authuser=0
Focus on 2. Enable App Verification and you will notice that recaptcha is just an alternative for SafetyNet.

Comment: This was bugging me for some time. No proper documentation. Thank you for this.

Comment: Spot on! Thank you for a working solution.  And for the record i think you mean SHA256 not SHA2.

Comment: Works for Android 11 and latest Firebase version

Comment: i'm not sure how this is related, because this is just another security measure. it's not required. in Chome - i don't see this error, only in Firefox. and at the moment it's to activate captcha which i don't like as a ui process...

Answer (score 4):

It had on the Ionic/Angular/Capacitor app too. i.e. Android and Chrome. Firebase Auth with Microsoft Login.

So I have cleared all the chrome browser data on the Android device and then no issues. i.e. working fine now.

More workarounds: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/4256

Answer (score 3):

I experienced the issue with an iphone web app. I went into Settings -> Safari and disabled 'Prevent Cross-Site Tracking'.

Comment: it solved problem with debugging and local dev, but how to solve it globally for customers that are using the app?

Answer (score 3):

#### I came across this error and this is how I fixed it!

- Go to your firebase's project console
- Expand the `Build` section and click on app check
- You will notice that your app is not registered on `SafetyNet`
- Firebase will auto-detect your SHA-256 certificate
- You will have to accept some terms and then you confirm

#### *NB: Note that `SafetyNet` is deprecated and will be soon removed, you should activate `Play Integrity`instead.*

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeing this with Firefox, it may be the problem described here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth?authuser=0#troubleshooting

> This can occur when the reCAPTCHA flow completes successfully but does not redirect the user back to the native application. If this occurs, the user is redirected to the fallback URL `PROJECT_ID.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler`. On Firefox browsers, opening native app links is disabled by default. If you see the above error on Firefox, follow the steps in [Set Firefox for Android to open links in native apps](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/set-firefox-android-open-links-native-apps) to enable opening app links.

Answer (score 0):

If you encounter an error while logging in with Twitter using Firebase Auth, you can resolve it by following these steps:

- Disable Firebase Twitter auth from the Firebase console.
- Go to your [twitter developer account](https://developer.twitter.com/) and update callback url to twittwersdk:// as shown below:[image: twitter callback url]
- Open android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml and insert the following code inside the  tag:.[image]
- For iOS, open ios/Runner/Info.plist and add the following code:[image: info.plist code]
- Update the callback URL in your Dart code as follows:[image]
- Now stop and re-run the app and you are god