# Unable to process request due to missing initial state( Firebase)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

A user of my website encountered an error message while attempting to sign up using GitHub on my React site from his chrome browser(mobile). I have integrated Firebase GitHub sign-in with the popup method.

> Unable to process request due to missing initial state. This may happen if browser sessionStorage is inaccessible or accidentally cleared.

Code for signup:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { GithubAuthProvider, signInWithPopup } from "firebase/auth"

import { auth } from "../firebase/config"
import { createUserProfileDocument } from "../firebase/createUserProfileDocument"

import { useAuthContext } from "./useAuthContext"

export const useSignup = () => {
  const [error, setError] = useState(false)
  const [isPending, setIsPending] = useState(false)
  const [isCancelled, setIsCancelled] = useState(false)
  const provider = new GithubAuthProvider()
  const { dispatch } = useAuthContext()

  const signup = async () => {
    setError(null)
    setIsPending(true)
    try {
      const res = await signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
      if (!res) {
        throw new Error("Could not complete signup")
      }
      const user = res.user
      await createUserProfileDocument(user)
      dispatch({ type: "LOGIN", payload: user })

      if (!isCancelled) {
        setIsPending(false)
        setError(null)
      }
    } catch (error) {
      if (!isCancelled) {
        setError(error.message)
        setIsPending(false)
      }
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => setIsCancelled(true)
  }, [])
  return { signup, error, isPending }
}
```

useAuthContext code:

```
import { useContext } from "react"

import { AuthContext } from "../context/AuthContext"

export const useAuthContext = () => {
  const context = useContext(AuthContext)

  if (!context) {
    throw Error("useAuthContext must be used inside an AuthContextProvider")
  }

  return context
}
```

AuthContext code

```
import { createContext, useEffect, useReducer } from "react"
import { onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth"

import { auth } from "../firebase/config"
import { authReducer } from "../reducers/authReducer"

export const AuthContext = createContext()

export const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(authReducer, {
    user: null,
    authIsReady: false,
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      dispatch({ type: "AUTH_IS_READY", payload: user })
    })
    return unsubscribe
  }, [])

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ ...state, dispatch }}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

firebaseConfig object:

```
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_ID,
  measurementId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MEASUREMENT_ID,
}

initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

const db = getFirestore()

const auth = getAuth()

export { auth, db, logEvent }
```

Comment: What does the `useAuthContext` hook look like?

Comment: @WesleyLeMahieu added code for useAuthContext

Comment: What are the keys (*not values*) inside of your `initializeApp` config object?

Comment: @WesleyLeMahieu Just added that in the question

Comment: Thanks. It really seems related to this thread https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/4256 --- which is unfortunately a long-running, unresolved issue many people face. It seems users on mobile are affected most. I'm not certain of a resolution yet.

Comment: It's working fine for most of the browsers but two users so far have reported this issue while signing up.

Comment: I have gone through that thread but didn't find any relevant solution over there.

Comment: You may need to register your app with SafetyNet with SHA2 --- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67373448/firebase-unable-to-process-request-due-to-missing-initial-state --- Let me know if that works as I would implement this on my stacks.

Comment: I think this solution is for Android apps, not websites.

Comment: Ah, you're correct. Is the end-user on Safari by chance? Another very relevant thread --- https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/6716 --- This user thread references this issue as well --- https://github.com/capawesome-team/capacitor-firebase/issues/224#issuecomment-1301740637

Comment: Hi Guys I am facing this same issue, I have tried adding AppCheck into the web Application but then that has resulted in another issue regarding `recaptcha-error` in `getToken` method. Any leads will be helpful

Answer (score -4):

I had the same issue, and I resolved it by changing the browser.

Go to settings.

Open Applications.

Select google, and change default browser to chrome

Also change it, in Samsung browser to Chrome.

That helped me.